# Impossible to download a file in CSV format

Tags: java, csv, google-drive-api

I'm running in a bit of a trouble using the Google Drive API.
I'm trying to download a spreadsheet from my own Google Drive using a Java app.

According to the documentation from Google ( https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads )
a spreadsheet can be download in CSV using the "text/csv" parameter. My problem is that when i'm trying to download my file in CSV i'm encoutering an error but in other  format its working.

The error i'm getting is :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeAndDownloadTo(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:541)
```

My code is the following :

```
public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException
        {
            Credential credential = authorize();
            return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            // Build a new authorized API client service.
            Drive service = getDriveService();

            // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
            FileList result = service.files().list().setPageSize(10).setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute();
            List<File> files = result.getFiles();
            if (files == null || files.size() == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("No files found.");
                }
            else
                {
                    for (File file : files)
                        {
                            if (file.getName().equals(Settings.DRIVE_FILE_NAME))
                                {
                                    System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
                                    String fileId = file.getId();
                                    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    service.files().export(fileId, "text/csv").executeAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
                                    System.out.println(outputStream);

                                }

                        }
                }
        }
```

Where am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try using methods executeMediaAndDownloadTo() instead of executeAndDownloadTo()

Comment: It's a server-side error. You need to look at the server logs to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Official Google Documentation, when you received '*500: Backend Error*' its an unexpected error occurred while processing the request.

The suggested action for this is to use '*exponential backoff*'. *Exponential backoff* is a standard error handling strategy for network applications in which the client periodically retries a failed request over an increasing amount of time. If a high volume of requests or heavy network traffic causes the server to return errors, exponential backoff may be a good strategy for handling those errors.

Exponential backoff increases the efficiency of bandwidth usage, reduces the number of requests required to get a successful response.

For more details, please follw the link: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#500_backend_error*emphasized text*

Comment: Is that Google' suggested action, or yours? A server error is a server error. There's no reason to believe repeating the request won't produce the same error. It needs to be *investigated* and *fixed* at the *server end.* Not just mindlessly repeated at runtime.

Comment: It is stated in Google documentation for Drive REST API that if you encounter the '500:Backend Error', the suggested action is to use 'exponential backoff'. Here's where I get my answer: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#500_backend_error

Comment: 500 errors are 50:50
Sometimes they are transient and will subsequently succeed after a backoff (although there may be so many backoffs needed that it's better to simply fail).
Other times there is a problem in your request that isn't being correctly dealt with by Google Drive. In such cases, backoffs won't help.

Comment: *Some* 500 errors are load-dependent and can be retried. Some are bugs innthe request or server application and will never work no matter how often you retry. The ratio between them could be anything, not just 50:50